# using globalize-webpack-plugin for production

Tags: webpack

I took this example and slightly edited:
https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize/tree/master/examples/app-npm-webpack

my package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "cldr-data": "^30.0.4",
    "globalize": "^1.2.2",
    "globalize-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.10",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2"
  }
}
```

my webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require( "webpack" );
var CommonsChunkPlugin = require( "webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin" );
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require( "html-webpack-plugin" );
var GlobalizePlugin = require( "globalize-webpack-plugin" );

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: "./src/app.js",
        vendor: [
            'globalize',
            'globalize/dist/globalize-runtime/number',
            'globalize/dist/globalize-runtime/currency',
            'globalize/dist/globalize-runtime/date',
            'globalize/dist/globalize-runtime/message',
            'globalize/dist/globalize-runtime/plural',
            'globalize/dist/globalize-runtime/relative-time',
            'globalize/dist/globalize-runtime/unit'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.[hash].js',
        path: './dist'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js"]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'test',
            filename: 'index.html'
        }),
        new GlobalizePlugin({
            production: true,
            developmentLocale: "en",
            supportedLocales: [ "en" ],
            messages: "messages/[locale].json",
            output: "i18n/[locale].[hash].js"
        }),
        new CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            filename: 'vendor.[hash].js'
        }),
    ]
};
```

and my app.js

```
var Globalize = require('globalize');
//var react = require('react'); //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

var f = Globalize.numberFormatter({ maximumFractionDigits: 0, useGrouping: false })

console.log(f(34.4535));
```

Then I wrote on the command line "webpack" and my application has gathered. Open the chrome and the app works. But I want to note the order of the connected files:

[image]

But if I uncomment the line var react = require('react'); and my application has gathered, Then when I open the chrome, I see the following:

[image]
[image]

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Define the order manually:

```
const CHUNK_ORDER = {
    "vendor": 1,
    "globalize-compiled-data-en": 2,
    "main": 3
};
```

And pass the sorting function:

```
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'test',
        filename: 'index.html',
        chunksSortMode: function(a, b) {
            return CHUNK_ORDER[a.names[0]] > CHUNK_ORDER[b.names[0]] ? 1 : -1;
        },
    }),
```